# How to change button text color in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am creating a tic-tac-toe game and I would like to change a button's text color when clicked. My button will either display X or O. I would like the X to be blue and O to be red.

This is my code:

```
 package com.example.d4rmybraine.tic_tac_toe;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

        private boolean player1Turn = true;

        private int roundCount;

        private int player1Points;
        private int player2Points;

        private TextView textViewPlayer1;
        private TextView textViewPlayer2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            textViewPlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p1);
            textViewPlayer2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p2);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                    buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
                    buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
                }
            }

            Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
            buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    resetGame();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
                return;
            }

            });

            if (player1Turn) {
                ((Button) v).setText("X");
            } else {
                ((Button) v).setText("O");
            }

            roundCount++;

            if (checkForWin()) {
                if (player1Turn) {
                    player1Wins();
                } else {
                    player2Wins();
                }
            } else if (roundCount == 9) {
                draw();
            } else {
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
            }

        }

        private boolean checkForWin() {
            String[][] field = new String[3][3];

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                        && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                        && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                        && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                        && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                    && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                    && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }

            if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                    && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                    && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void player1Wins() {
            player1Points++;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updatePointsText();
            resetBoard();
        }

        private void player2Wins() {
            player2Points++;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Player 2 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updatePointsText();
            resetBoard();
        }

        private void draw() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            resetBoard();
        }

        private void updatePointsText() {
            textViewPlayer1.setText("Player 1: " + player1Points);
            textViewPlayer2.setText("Player 2: " + player2Points);
        }

        private void resetBoard() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    buttons[i][j].setText("");
                }
            }

            roundCount = 0;
            player1Turn = true;
        }

        private void resetGame() {
            player1Points = 0;
            player2Points = 0;
            updatePointsText();`enter code here`
            resetBoard();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

            outState.putInt("roundCount", roundCount);
            outState.putInt("player1Points", player1Points);
            outState.putInt("player2Points", player2Points);
            outState.putBoolean("player1Turn", player1Turn);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

            roundCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("roundCount");
            player1Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player1Points");
            player2Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player2Points");
            player1Turn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("player1Turn");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't pad your post to avoid the error that it's mostly code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (player1Turn) {
     ((Button) v).setText("X");
     ((Button) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
} else {
     ((Button) v).setText("O");
     ((Button) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
}
```